# elpy on Windows: M-x elpy-config results in "Neither easy_install nor pip found"

Tags: microsoft-windows, elpy

I have trouble to get `elpy` working on Windows 10 with Emacs 27 (Downloaded from http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/emacs/windows/emacs-27/emacs-27.2-x86_64-installer.exe).

When I do `M-x elpy-config` I got the error message *Neither easy_install nor pip found*. That makes it impossible for me to check out the great elpy config buffer that would show me what elpy is missing.

Python 3.9.10 is installed. I am able to invoke it via `py -3` and `python` on the windows command prompt. Also `pip` and `py -3 -m pip` are working well.

Values of the Windows `PATH`:

```
echo %PATH%
C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Scripts\;C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\;C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;
```

Values of `exec-path`:

```
exec-path is a variable defined in C source code.

Value
("c:/Windows/system32" "C:/Windows" "C:/Windows/System32/Wbem" "C:/Windows/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0/" "C:/Windows/System32/OpenSSH/" "C:/Users/user/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python39/Scripts/" "C:/Users/user/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python39/" "C:/Users/user/AppData/Local/Microsoft/WindowsApps" "." "c:/Program Files/Emacs/x86_64/libexec/emacs/27.2/x86_64-w64-mingw32")

Original Value
("c:/Windows/system32" "c:/Windows" "c:/Windows/System32/Wbem" "c:/Windows/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0" "c:/Windows/System32/OpenSSH" "c:/Users/user/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python39/Scripts" "c:/Users/user/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python39" "c:/Users/user/AppData/Local/Microsoft/WindowsApps" "." "c:/Program Files/Emacs/x86_64/libexec/emacs/27.2/x86_64-w64-mingw32")
```

btw: I do not know why `x86_64-w64-mingw32` is part of the `exec-path`. This does not exist on my system; MinGW is not installed.

There is also an [open issue](https://github.com/jorgenschaefer/elpy/issues/1961) about that problem.

Comment: Where did you get the emacs from - the link please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you use Windows, check the python installation path with the command `where python` in windows command prompt. Then use the obtained value in the following snippet:

```lisp
(setenv "PATH" (concat "/Users/yourname/.pyenv/shims/python:"
                       (getenv "PATH")))
(add-to-list 'exec-path "/Users/yourname/.pyenv/shims/python")
```

(The path shown is for my system, replace it with your value).

This is caused by the emacs having two path, as shown, which must be in sync to work. Some people disagree with that, in *nix systems usually the package `exec-path-from-shell` is used, but that do not work in Windows.

Comment: I will test that but I assume this would not help because the value from `where python` is still set to `PATH` and `exec-path` as you can see in my question.

Comment: I rejected elpy and now use Emacs own `python` mode and `eglot` as an lsp solution.